# Sticky navbar not working after page loading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Sticky navbar is working properly but when i scroll down and new items getting loaded on page then it's not working it's getting fixed at top even when scroll and reach top of the page. How to fix it?

```
var $window = $(window);
    $window.on('scroll', function () {
        var scroll = $window.scrollTop();
        if (scroll < 300) {
            $(".sticky").removeClass("is-sticky");
        } else {
            $(".sticky").addClass("is-sticky");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where's the css that makes the "is-sticky" class work?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this :

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById(".sticky");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("is-sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("is-sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```